# React-select does not display selected option

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have in state selectTry={} empty object. select dropdown is displayed with options. I can also perform search in it but when I select (with or without search) the value does not reflect in the select input field. In handlechange I can see selection happened with console logs. Any thing I am doing wrong ?

React select version 3.1.0 And I also see React Strict mode warning regarding findDOMNode method should not be accessed.

The expected output is default selection of first dealer and on change selected dealer should be visible

```
    {dealers && dealers.length > 0 ? (
                    <Select
                      backspaceRemovesValue={false}
                      controlShouldRenderValue={false}
                      hideSelectedOptions={false}
                      isClearable={false}
                      onChange={(value) => this.handleChange(value)}
                      options={dealers.map((data: any) => ({
                        value: data.dealerId,
                        label: data.name,
                      }))}
    
                      tabSelectsValue={false}
    
                      value={this.state.selectTry.value}
    
                      defaultValue={{
                        value: dealers[0].dealerId,
                        label: dealers[0].name,
                      }}
```

***handlechange***

```
    handleChange = (info: any) => {
        this.setState({ selectTry: info });
      }
```

****Default State

````
```
    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: this.props.selectedIndex,
      isArrowDownClicked: false,
      rotation: 0,
      showProfileMenu: false,
      utilState: any,
      selectedDealer: +this.props.userState.selectedDealerDropdown,
      userDetails: any,
      dealers: [],
      selectTry: {},
````

****console log **
***inside handlechange info** {value: 147, label: "Healthcare INC"}
this.state.selectTry after handle change {}

Comment: Try change your value to this `value={this.state.selectTry}` !

Comment: Thanks for commenting  @b3hr4d. I tried it nothing changed. Also I am not sure why default option is not getting dispayed !!!

Comment: So can you share the full component?

Comment: I tried value={this.state.selectTry[0]} this too. Not happening. The component I cant share (sorry). Please share doc link you are referring to

Comment: https://react-select.com/home#creatable share your default state.

Comment: I have added default state in the question

Comment: Also can u share your `handleChange = (info: any) =>` console.log(info) ?

Comment: selectTry is empty object. I have edited question with logs.

Comment: What happened when you didn't pass the value?

Comment: selectTry is updating with a lag. On next change I see last change in console log